# Is there a way to get a good human readable error from a COM error in arcEngine?

Tags: arcgis-engine

I'm trying to perform the following operation:

```
 IPropertySet addressProperties = reverseGeocoding.ReverseGeocode(point, false);
```

And I get this error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040217

Is there some function to get a human readable form of this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often you can use the [`ISupportErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221083.aspx) interface and [`GetErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221032.aspx) system call in conjunction; many classes implement this to provide human-readable exception data.

Also, [some common `HRESULT` codes for geocoding](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00310000000s000000).

Comment: Wow: GEOCODING_E_REVERSE_GEOCODE_NO_ADDRESS_FOUND. They really ought to have the HRESULTs on that page as well (I sent feedback on that page requesting that they include the HRESULT value, but I haven't had a lot of luck with sending feedback to them in the past).

Comment: There is no need to access ISupportErrorInfo in .NET, since any errors are translated to a COMException which, if the class implements ISupportErrorInfo, does include the available information.

Answer (score 6):

So far I have not found anything to help me ease the debugging experience of the ESRI `COMException`, and therefore decided to try and do something about it. I put the [solution](https://gist.github.com/furier/6153975#file-esrierrorcodeinterpreter-cs) on gist.github.com for everybody to use.

I used the resource [ArcObjects error codes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/ArcObjects_error_codes/0001000002zz000000/) and copied all the error messages with codes and enums into a text file, about 1900+ lines. Not all exceptions are documented even, and many are just to generic to get anything useful out of.

The "enums" look like this `CADASTRAL_E_OPERATION_FAILED`, with a regex I then picked out "*the first word the underscore and then the second word*" `CADASTRAL_E` as that seemed to be a common *pattern* that i could group the error codes by per `assembly/namespace`

I then filled a second text file with the shortened enums and the belonging `assemblies/namespaces`.

When that was done I created a console project, where i read all the lines from the two files and with an algorithm created a `Dictionary` with the `namespaces` as `key`, and the `value` as a second `Dictionary` where the `key` was the 10 digit `error code`, and the `value` as an `EsriError` class containing the message etc.

In the end I then wrote out the code as a `Dictionary initializer` to a new text file by iterating over the `Dictionaries`, and then copied the code into my project.

Since the `COMException.Source` attribute sais which `assembly/namespace` the error was thrown in,
I can use that to lookup the `Dictionary` containing all the error codes for that assembly.

To find the correct message to go with the error code i then do a lookup in the retrieved dictionary with the `COMException.ErrorCode` as the `key`, and then I either get back the error message or an message telling me that the `ComExceptionInterpreter` had no message associated with the error code.

Hope this will help somebody, and if anybody have anything to add, let me know!
You can also fork the gist to make it your own.

[ESRI Error Lookup Utility](https://gist.github.com/furier/6153975#file-esrierrorcodeinterpreter-cs)

Comment: This is a very useful piece of work ! But note, that in many cases there are error codes that are either generic (e.g "unspecified error") or they are simply not documented at all. There are also cases where the same generic error string is re-used, e.g "SDE Error.". However, the error itself is described in the enum, for example: FDO_E_SE_INVALID_USER -2147216118 "SDE Error." could be altered to FDO_E_SE_INVALID_USER -2147216118 "SDE Invalid user." It should therefore be possible to add an error string with a more descriptive message. Good work !

Comment: While that's handy, I don't really see why you asked the question to which you already knew the answer and wrote the code to.

Comment: Well, you know that there is an option to answer your question straight away while writing your question. I wanted to contribute my work to the community so hopefully somebody wouldn't have to do this all over again, but if people don't feel its usefull sure ill take it away...

Comment: I'm not detracting from its usefulness, it's just that this answer should be merged with @patrickinmpls thread. At any rate, this can be considered a duplicate thread.

Answer (score 4):

Convert the Hex code to Decimal.

I usually take these steps:

1. Convert the HRESULT to binary

   ```
      8    0    0    4    0    2    1    7
   1000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0010 0001 0111
   ```
2. Since the most significant digit is 1, the number is negative. We must calculate the 2's compliment. First, find the 1's compliment by NOT'ing the binary number.

   ```
   0111 1111 1111 1011 1111 1101 1110 1000
   ```
3. Now add 1 to make the 2's compliment

   ```
   0111 1111 1111 1011 1111 1101 1110 1001
   ```
4. Convert the new binary number to decmial (I use [this page](http://mistupid.com/computers/binaryconv.htm))

   ```
   -2147220969
   ```

Comment: Frankly, the decimal equivalent of the hex error code is even *harder* for a human to read. Typically such error codes are either (a) abstract values that index into a list of explanations, in which case the conversion is useless, or (b) a concatenation of bits, each of which provides a discrete binary flag, in which case the conversion makes it much more difficult to identify the bit pattern.

Answer (score 2):

**COMException** class has the **ErrorCode** property, which you can compare against any of the error code enumerations, for example **esriGeocodingError**.

Comment: Do you have any clever way of getting the enum string corresponding to the ErrorCode property in a generic way, like if you don't know in advance which enumeration it is in?

Comment: I also see that the enumerations have summaries that could possibly be retrieved as well. Seems like there would be something built in to put 2 and 2 together...

Comment: @blah238, did you ever develop a way to get the ErrorCode in a generic way?  Also, do you know how to access each error enumeration's summary?  I can see the summary when I hover over the enum in Vis Studio, but am not sure you to actually capture it programmatically.

Comment: @blah238 and rgwozdz if you take a look at my answer to this post, its the closest iv gotten to getting a generic human readable error message, just feed the COMException to the error lookup method and you will get it.