# ESRI Error lookup COM Exceptions

Tags: arcobjects

**How do I decipher these cryptic `COMExceptions` that *ArcObjects* are throwing?**

I got this exception `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: HResult: 0x8004151C` and thats it, no more info no nothing. How do I go about debugging?

I managed to decipher the exception after hours of googling, talking to colleagues, searching ESRI's forums and resources and at last gis.stackexchange.com.

I found this resource [ArcObjects error codes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/ArcObjects_error_codes/0001000002zz000000/) and some other resource I cant manage to find again, where I was supposed to use the calculator in scientific mode, and do 10 steps of stuff get a 10 digit error code.

While doing so I couldn't help but get annoyed and wonder if this is the way its meant to be, or if there is any solution, code or anything else out there that could ease the job.

Or do we developer really have to wait for an exception to happen, and then do a manually lookup on the internet and maybe, just maybe find the cause for the exception after a long period of time?

So thats why I'm asking here, hence the question in the top.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2664/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-good-human-readable-error-from-a-com-error-in-arcengine